# Transparent picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I'm trying to add an icon to a Win Forms project, but I can't get the transparency working. I've tried with several different images but I'm not able to set the background color to blue.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change back color of picturebox to Color.Transparent.

You can also try to use png file with transparency channel.

Comment: Setting the background color to transparent doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

The PictureBox is transparent, you need to use a transparent image (such as a PNG), as already stated.